# Why does the build fail when I run unit tests in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

When I try and run even the default unit tests in Xcode foir a Swift project, the build fails.

```
import Cocoa
import XCTest

class Test2: XCTestCase {

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

override func tearDown() {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    super.tearDown()
}

func testExample() {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}

func testPerformanceExample() {
    // This is an example of a performance test case.
    self.measureBlock() {
        // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
    }
}
```

}

[image]

This happens on both my own MBP and the one that my employer provides. I can't help thinking that it's to do with the project settings.

Works fine for Objective-C tests.

Any help would be very much appreciated, I've pulled out what little remaining hair there is.

Comment: It his an iOS or an OS X project?

Comment: It's an iOS project. Oddly I just created a blank iOS project and all was well with the blank unit tests. So I'll recreate my project and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally added an OS X Test Case (you can see this because of the `import Cocoa`). This happens sometimes because Xcode selects the wrong source.

When you add tests to you project make sure that those are iOS tests.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! That did the job nicely :)